# Kafka consumer using Apache Camel

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-camel

I am new to Apache camel. we are doing POC to develop kafka consumer using Camel. Below is the sample code.

```
    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder(){

      @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         from("kafka:{{consumer.topic}}?brokers={{kafka.host}}:{{kafka.port}}" 
                     + "&consumersCount={{consumer.consumersCount}}" 
                     + "&seekTo={{consumer.seekTo}}" 
                     + "&groupId={{consumer.group}}")
             .process(new Processor() {

                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

                    Message message = exchange.getIn();
                    Object data = message.getBody();

                    System.out.println(data);
                }
             })
             .to("seda:end");


  });

        context.start();

    ConsumerTemplate template=context.createConsumerTemplate();
    String info=template.receiveBody("seda:end",String.class);

    System.out.println(info);
}
```

I am having below issues:

1. Context stops immediately after start.
2. If I poll To endpoint using consumer template, it does not print anything whereas inside .process(), I am able to print kafka messages when I start context in infinite loop. Why consumer template is not able to print.

Comment: There is a Kafka example at
https://github.com/apache/camel-examples/blob/master/examples/camel-example-kafka/README.adoc The start method is not blocking, see this blog
https://tomd.xyz/camel-standalone-example/ And if you want to keep running Camel standalone, there is camel-main, see
https://github.com/apache/camel-examples/tree/master/examples/camel-example-main

Comment: @ClausIbsen - Thanks for the links. As per link -  github.com/apache/camel-examples/tree/master/examples/…  , I have put  to  add  Thread.sleep() which will keep camel running for time specified in " Thread.sleep()" .  But I want to let consumer run forever unless there is some maintenance issues. Using " Thread.sleep()" will always put time limit to consumer run.  Do I need put context.start() in infinite  while loop if I want to run forever?

Answer (score 1):

1. As Claus already commented, your Camel Context is shutting down immediately because it is not blocking. See the links in his comment.
2. I think you missed a `template.start();` to start your Consumer. See [this link](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Fuse_ESB/4.4.1/html/Programing_EIP_Components/files/Templates-Consumer.html) for an example.

Comment: I have started the context with command as context.start(). I checked your link and they are doing same as i mentioned in the code above.

Comment: Consumer, not context. You create your consumer after you started the context. I guess you have to start your consumer too.